# How to do memoization or memoisation in Julia 1.0

Tags: julia

I have been trying to do memorisation in Julia for the Fibonacci function. This is what I came up with.

The original unmodified code (for control purposes)

```
function fib(x)
    if x < 3
        return 1
    else
        return fib(x-2) + fib(x-1)
    end
end
```

This is my first attempt

```
memory=Dict()

function memfib(x)
    global memory
    if haskey(memory,x)
        return memory[x]
    else
        if x < 3
            return memory[x] = 1
        else
            return memory[x] = memfib(x-2) + memfib(x-1)
        end
    end
end
```

My second attempt

```
memory=Dict()

function membetafib(x)
    global memory
    return haskey(memory,x) ? memory[x] : x < 3 ? memory[x]=1 : memory[x] = membetafib(x-2) + membetafib(x-1)
end
```

My third attempt

```
memory=Dict()

function memgammafib!(memory,x)
    return haskey(memory,x) ? memory[x] : x < 3 ? memory[x]=1 : memory[x] = memgammafib!(memory,x-2) + memgammafib!(memory,x-1)
end
```

Are there other ways of doing so that I am not aware of?

Comment: Have you tried the [`Memoize.jl`](https://github.com/simonster/Memoize.jl) package?

Comment: You could use something like `get!(memory, x) do; x < 3 ? 1 memfib(x-1) + memfib(x-2) end`. But other than that: this question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since you are asking about improvements for working code.

Comment: I think the question fits great here. Supplying a worked example just makes it easier to answer.

Answer (score 19):

As pointed out in the comments, the [Memoize.jl](https://github.com/simonster/Memoize.jl) package is certainly the easiest option. This requires you to mark the method at definition time.

By far the most powerful approach, however, is to use [Cassette.jl](https://github.com/jrevels/Cassette.jl), which lets you add memoization to pre-existing functions, e.g.

```
fib(x) = x < 3 ? 1 : fib(x-2) + fib(x-1)

using Cassette
Cassette.@context MemoizeCtx
function Cassette.overdub(ctx::MemoizeCtx, ::typeof(fib), x)
       get(ctx.metadata, x) do
           result = recurse(ctx, fib, x)
           ctx.metadata[x] = result
           return result
       end
   end
```

A little bit of a description of what is going on:

- `MemoizeCtx` is the Cassette "context" which we are defining
- [`overdub`](https://jrevels.github.io/Cassette.jl/latest/api.html#Cassette.overdub) is run instead of the original function definition

  - We use this to check if the arg exists in the metadata dictionary.
  - `recurse(...)` tells Cassette to call the function, but ignore the top level `overload`.

Now we can run the function with memoization:

```
Cassette.overdub(MemoizeCtx(metadata=Dict{Int,Int}()), fib, 80)
```

Now what's even cooler is that we can take an existing function which calls `fib`, and memoize the call to `fib` *inside* that function:

```
function foo()
    println("calling fib")
    @show fib(80)
    println("done.")
end
Cassette.overdub(MemoizeCtx(metadata=Dict{Int,Int}()), foo)
```

(Cassette is still pretty hard on the compiler, so this may take a while to run the first time, but will be fast after that).

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to do it is to use [`get!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.get!)

```
const fibmem = Dict{Int,Int}()
function fib(n)
    get!(fibmem, n) do
        n < 3 ? 1 : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    end
end
```

Note the [`const`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#const) specifier outside `fibmem`. This avoids the need for `global`, and will make the code faster as it allows the compiler to use type inference within `fib`.

Comment: Can you please explain the syntax here? Specifically the "do" and the "? 1 :"?

Comment: `do` is a block syntax for function arguments: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments

Comment: `_ ? _ : _` is a short form for writing `if _; _ else _ end`, known as the "ternary operator": https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#man-conditional-evaluation

Comment: Thanks so much. Super helpful. I'm one day into Julia and I'm very impressed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the arguments to the function are integers, you can use a simple array, which will be faster than a `Dict` (make sure you use `BigInt`s in the cache for large arguments to avoid overflow):

```
function fib(n, cache=sizehint!(BigInt[0,1],n))
    n < length(cache) && return cache[n+1]
    f = fib(n-1,cache) + fib(n-2,cache)
    push!(cache,f)
    return f
end
```