# Using caching instead of memoization to speedup a function

Tags: julia

While memoization of a function is a good idea, it could cause a program to crash because the program could potentially run out of memory.

Therefore it is NOT A SAFE OPTION to be used in a production program.

Instead I have developed caching with a fixed memory slots below with a soft limit and hard limit. When the cache slots is above the hard limit, it will have the least used slots deleted until the number of slots is reduced to the soft limit.

```
struct cacheType
    softlimit::Int
    hardlimit::Int
    memory::Dict{Any,Any}
    freq::Dict{Any,Int}
    cacheType(soft::Int,hard::Int) = new(soft,hard,Dict(),Dict())
end

function tidycache!(c::cacheType)
    memory_slots=length(c.memory)
    if memory_slots > c.hardlimit
        num_to_delete = memory_slots - c.softlimit
        # Now sort the freq dictionary into array of key => AccessFrequency
        # where the first few items have the lowest AccessFrequency
        for item in sort(collect(c.freq),by = x -> x[2])[1:num_to_delete]
            delete!(c.freq, item[1])
            delete!(c.memory, item[1])
        end
    end
end

# Fibonacci function  
function cachefib!(cache::cacheType,x)
    if haskey(cache.memory,x)
        # Increment the number of times this key has been accessed
        cache.freq[x] += 1
        return cache.memory[x]
    else
        # perform housekeeping and remove cache entries if over the hardlimit
        tidycache!(cache)
        if x < 3
            cache.freq[x] = 1
            return cache.memory[x] = 1
        else
            result = cachefib!(cache,x-2) + cachefib!(cache,x-1)
            cache.freq[x] = 1
            cache.memory[x] = result
            return result
        end
    end
end

c = cacheType(3,4)
cachefib!(c,3)
cachefib!(c,4)
cachefib!(c,5)
cachefib!(c,6)
cachefib!(c,4)
println("c.memory is ",c.memory)
println("c.freq is ",c.freq)
```

I think this would be most useful in a production environment than just using memorization with no limits of memory consumption which could result in a program crashing.

In Python language, they have

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False)

Decorator to wrap a function with a memoizing callable that saves up to the maxsize most recent calls. It can save time when an expensive or I/O bound function is periodically called with the same arguments.

Since a dictionary is used to cache results, the positional and keyword arguments to the function must be hashable.

Is there an equivalent in Julia language?

Comment: Do you mean [_memoization_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (without the 'r')? I don't think there is anything that prevents limiting memory use in memoization.

Comment: I do like the option of limiting memory use.

Comment: Kinda think this should go on [Julia's Discourse page](https://discourse.julialang.org). There, you'll get lots of feedback. Stack Overflow is for getting specific broken things to work.

Answer (score 2):

There is [LRUCache.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/LRUCache.jl), which provides an `LRU` type which basically acts like a `Dict`. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with the Memoize.jl package, but you can use [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52084004/392585):

```
using LRUCache

const fibmem = LRU{Int,Int}(3) # store only 3 values
function fib(n)
    get!(fibmem, n) do
        n < 3 ? 1 : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work and I have download the LRUCache.jl and list.jl into my modules directory